# combining xml, xpath or xquery

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xquery

```
<main>
    <parent>
        <parentId>parentId1</parentId>
        <aParentField>aParentValue
        </aParentField>
    </parent>
    <child>
        <parentId>parentId1</parentId>
        <aChildField>aChildValue
        </aChildField>
    </child>
</main>
```

I am new to XML and was trying to combine A and B using the ID as a parameter to combine, so the result should be like:

```
<main>
    <parent>
        <parentId>parentId1</parentId>
        <aParentField>aParentValue
        </aParentField>
        <child>
            <aChildField>aChildValue
        </aChildField>
        </child>
    </parent>
</main>
```

What can be used and how ?

Comment: Do you need to generate the XMLFile or your resulting object should be of the desired format ?

Comment: The resulting object should be of the desired format.@Maddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example is a little ambiguous. Assuming your input can have multiple `parent` nodes, each linked to multiple `child` nodes, I would suggest you use a **[key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key)** to resolve the cross-references:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="child" match="child" use="parentId" />

<xsl:template match="/main">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="parent"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="parent">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('child', parentId)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="child">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::parentId)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What if we have one more child saying child2 with the same content? @michael.hor257k

Comment: @Tarun Try it and see.

Comment: It worked but i have a different problem with the nested elements https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40493838/combining-xml-using-xslt-1-0