# Combining XML using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to map the following but its difficult because it has different names:

```xml
<main>
    <order>
        <ID>123</ID>
        <Name>ABC</Name>
    </order>
    <order>
        <ID>4556</ID>
        <Name>AAA</Name>
        <ParentID>123</ParentID>
    </order>
</main>
```

The result should be:

```xml
<main>
    <order>
        <ID>123</ID>
        <Name>ABC</Name>
        <order>
            <ID>4556</ID>
            <Name>AAA</Name>
            <ParentID>123</ParentID>
        </order>
    </order>
</main>
```

Comment: I don't see how this is different from your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40428756/combining-xml-xpath-or-xquery

Comment: in this case wee are comparing orders with ID and parent ID which are differed "use" in the key @michael.hor257k

Comment: I believe it's the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @michael.hor257k said, conceptually this question is the same as your previous question. I think you're just not understanding the concept. Hopefully the comments in my example will help.

If I understand the question correctly, you want to nest `order` elements inside of their "parent" `order` element based on `ParentID`. Since we're basing it on the ParentID, that's what we'll use for our key...

**XML Input**

```
<main>
    <order>
        <ID>123</ID>
        <Name>ABC</Name>
    </order>

    <order>
        <ID>4556</ID>
        <Name>AAA</Name>
        <ParentID>123</ParentID>
    </order>
</main>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!--Create a key containing order elements that contain a non-empty ParentID.-->
  <xsl:key name="orderByParentId" match="order[string(ParentID)]" use="ParentID"/>

  <!--Identity transform (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying)-->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/main">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!--To get the high level order elements, only apply-templates when order
      does not contain a non-empty ParentID child.-->
      <xsl:apply-templates 
        select="@*|order[not(string(ParentID))]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="order">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!--Don't apply-templates to ParentID; we don't want to keep those.
      Do apply-templates to the key 'orderByParentId' when the key matches
      the current order's ID child.-->
      <xsl:apply-templates 
        select="@*|*[not(self::ParentID)]|key('orderByParentId',ID)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<main>
   <order>
      <ID>123</ID>
      <Name>ABC</Name>
      <order>
         <ID>4556</ID>
         <Name>AAA</Name>
      </order>
   </order>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach to copy all `order` nodes with index `n>1` into the first one is the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="text()" />    <!-- suppresses copying of text() nodes -->

    <xsl:template match="main">        <!-- replicates the "main" node -->
      <main>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </main>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="order[1]">    <!-- matches the first "order" node and copies all following ones -->
      <order>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::order" />
      </order>   
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<main>
    <order>
        <ID>123</ID>
        <Name>ABC</Name>
        <order>
            <ID>4556</ID>
            <Name>AAA</Name>
            <ParentID>123</ParentID>
        </order>
    </order>
</main>
```

Comment: what if there are many orders and i just want to group them basing on their ID where the  order with same Parent ID matching the ID of the other order, the must be merged. not all the orders present. @zx485

Comment: @Tarun: Sorry, I do not even remotely understand your additional question. michael.hor257k above told you that this question may have been quite similar to one of your previous questions. I answered it anyway. But your comment seems to indicate a whole new set of parameters which you better should put into a new question with a precise [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the desired outcome.